# Incorrect image padding

Tags: imageresizer

I searched and tried the troubleshooting faqs but can't see a reference to the problem I'm having.

I have the following presets in the resizer section my web.config:

name="kbp600w" defaults="w=600;h=600;mode=max;anchor=MiddleCenter;watermark=kbp600"

name="kbp600"  defaults="w=600;h=600;anchor=MiddleCenter;bgcolor=FEF2E1;watermark=kbp600"

name="kbp300"  defaults="w=300;h=300;anchor=MiddleCenter;bgcolor=FEF2E1;watermark=kbp300"

I generate my images with the following urls (I generate three different images using the same file):

picture.jpg?preset=kbp600w

picture.jpg?preset=kbp300

picture.jpg?preset=kbp600

So, here's the thing:

The first URL works fine and does everything defined in the preset.

The second URL also works fine and does everything defined in the preset.

The third URL works fine when the image width is larger than the height (landscape), but when the height is the largest dimension (portrait) it resizes the height correctly but the width dimension does not get padded to fill the 600px width but instead becomes whatever size is calculated to maintain the aspect ratio. I need it to always have dimensions of 600 x 600 with padding either on the top and bottom or sides with the appropriate background color for the padding.

Am I doing something wrong?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5672886

Answer (score 0):

### Use `mode=pad` *and* `scale=canvas` (or `scale=both`) to always get exactly the requested dimensions.

Without scale=both or scale=canvas, an image < 600x600 in either dimension won't be upscaled or padded.

P.S. Anchor=MiddleCenter is the default, so you don't need to specify that.

Comment: That was exactly it. In each case one of the dimensions was 600 and the other was smaller. Now that you've said it I remember reading it, but there's so much to take in!
Thank you so much.